# CSS left, position and floating ...Different result in multiple browsers

Tags: html, css

left, position and floating. Different result in multiple browsers. What's hapenning in here? Thanks in advance!

Image here [CSSProblem](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/9684/whywl.jpg)

Here is the Index.css with the header values

```
            #static_header { background: url('white_grid_bg.png') repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; height: 80px; border-top: 1px solid rgb(201, 208, 214); width:100%; position: relative; }
            #static_header .link_wrapper { width: 960px; padding: 0px 10px; margin: auto; }
            #static_header .link_wrapper a { float: right; position: relative; text-transform: uppercase; }

            #static_header .link_wrapper img { float: right; position: relative; top: 26px; /*padding-right: -154px;*/  padding-left:15px;border-left: 1px dotted black;z-index:8;  width: 11%; }
            #static_header .link_wrapper .txtlink { top: 30px; margin-right: 20px; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(105, 113, 126); text-decoration: none; padding: 1px 0px; }
            #static_header .link_wrapper a.txtlink:hover, #static_header .link_wrapper a.txtlink.active { color: rgb(17, 68, 132); border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(50, 142, 236); }
            #static_header .link_wrapper #header_logo { float: left; background: url('aspelogo6.png') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; height: 90px; width:90px; top: 3px; position: relative; z-index: 400;  left: 0px; margin-left: -98px;display:block; width:10%; }
```

Here is the HTML code for Navigation

```
        <!-- Navigation Panel -->
        <div class="container">

            <div >  
              <ul id="nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com/" >Catalogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com/" >Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com/" >About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com/" >Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Here is the Navigation stylesheet

```
            /*  NAVIGATION Buttons*/
            #nav { top: -1091px; padding-top: 0.85em; width: 50%;font-family:'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif; font-size: 1.4em; position:relative; z-index:118;  float:right; right: 290px;  }
            #nav li { margin: 0 0 0.5em 0; display: block; float: left; clear: none; margin-right: 2.5%; background:#d18b5e; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;}
            #nav li:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
            #nav a { display: block; color: #FFF; text-decoration:none; }
            #nav a:hover { color: #484a50; border-bottom-color: #484a50; }
```

Comment: can you show code or live link or fiddle ?

Comment: try neatbean ... its cool and  intelligent .. will boost your coding speed

Comment: yes fiddle your code Or post your code.

Comment: `What's hapenning in here?` You want us to explain your image? Or you provide us some code and we can help you with HTML and CSS. Btw, remove that jquery and javascript tags, they don't belong here.

Comment: Your entire description of what you've done is "left, position and floating", and you expect us to be able to explain why various browsers are rendering your code in a certain way? Please edit your question to include: 1. The code that you've written that isn't behaving how you expect. 2. A description of how the code is behaving. (You've done well on this already by including a screenshot, although it wouldn't hurt to mention which browsers it's working and not working in in your question text.) 3. A description of how you expect the code to behave.

Comment: @NullPointer: I don't think your comment is relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The code is in the image posted. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite its just a suggestion .... i saw op is using notepad ....

Comment: @NullPointer: sure, but it's nothing to do with the OP's question, and I can't find any mention of a legimate app called "Neatbean" on the internet. The top Google result is what looks like a spam blog.

Comment: @GherghescuValentin: sure, but code in images isn't particularly helpful. If someone wants to give you amended code that works, they have to type in the code in your image, as opposed to copying and pasting it.

Comment: someone broke the post. please pay attention on the top guys.

Comment: Here is the reedited question. Now you can also see the code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `position:relative` to the container div for the navigation and then `position:absolute;` the navigation.

The `float:right;` and `position:relative;` are not playing nice.

Comment: Solved the problem by creating a container div for the navigation elements. The code looks like this... #container_nav { width: 100%; float:right; position: absolute;}
    '#nav { top: -1091px; padding-top: 0.85em; width: 50%;font-family:'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif; font-size: 1.4em; position:relative; z-index:118;  float:right; right: 290px;  display:block; margin-left:-20%; }' Thank you!